# Objective C Block Generics

Tags: ios, objective-c, generics, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to implement a datasource that can be used to customize several different classes of cells for a tableview, but I'm having trouble with a generic type in a block that I'm passing to the constructor.

Here is the implementation of the header file of the datasource :

```
@interface ABParseDatasource<__covariant ObjectType: UITableViewCell *> : NSObject <UITableViewDataSource>

- (instancetype)initWithCellIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier parseQuery:(PFQuery *)query tableView:(UITableView *)tableView customizeBlock:(void (^)(ObjectType))customBlock;

@end
```

And here is where I'm trying to initialize the block in the constructor :

```
self.parseDatasource = [[ABParseDatasource alloc] initWithCellIdentifier:identifier parseQuery:[ABOrder query] tableView:self.tableView customizeBlock:^(ABOrderItemTableViewCell *cell) {

}];
```

The property declaration :

```
@property (nonatomic) ABParseDatasource<ABOrderItemTableViewCell *> *parseDatasource;
```

But I'm getting a compiler error when instantiating the datasource :

[image]

Any ideas? (And yes `ABOrderItemTableViewCell` does inherit from `UITableViewCell`)

Comment: How do you declare that `init...` in `@implementation`?

Comment: @Sulthan - (instancetype)initWithCellIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier parseQuery:(PFQuery *)query tableView:(UITableView *)tableView customizeBlock:(void (^)(UITableViewCell *, PFObject *))customBlock { and on imgur http://imgur.com/ibKI2K9.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the generic type when creating the class:

```
[[ABParseDatasource<ABOrderItemTableViewCell *> alloc] initWithCellIdentifier...
```

Comment: Generics in Obj-C are not user friendly, they are there for a better interoperability with Swift, not to make Obj-C better.

Comment: +1 @Sulthan Beside the fact, that dynamic typed languages have "built-in generics" (`id` typed references). "Template-like" generics are a technology to break limitations of static typed languages. For a dynamic typed language there is no limitation one has to break.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I'd long been wondering how to make generics work with initializers!