# Objective C generics in blocks

Tags: objective-c, generics, objective-c-blocks

Despite its name, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32682257/objective-c-block-generics) doesn't seem to address it.

Is it possible to use Objective-C generics with blocks?

Something like:

```
typedef void (^MyResultBlock<__covariant ObjectType>)(NSArray<ObjectType> *items);
```

...and then declaring a block:

```
MyResultBlock<NSNumber> blockName = ^void(NSArray<NSNumber> *items) {...};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Objective-C generics are only for classes, not `typedef`s.